# Create a text on background image on a Raspberry pi in fullscreen mode

Tags: python, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I'm new here, so I'm hoping to ask correctly.

I want to program a GUI on a raspberry pi in fullscreen mode with python. I managed to display a background image. Now I'm trying to get a simple text on it, but I'm not managing to do that. I searched a lot but didn't find any solution to my problem. Pls help!

Here my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk

window = Tk()
C = canvas(window, height = 500, width=800)
C.pack()

image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file = "home/pi/Downloads/background3.jpg")
background_label = Label(window, image = image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)

Label(window, text="Hello", fg="black").pack()


window.attributes('-fullscreen', True)
windows.mainloop()
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the create_image and create_text methods of the canvas to overlay text on an image. Just add your image, the text you want and the fullscreen command to the below example to get what you want.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk

window = Tk()
c = Canvas(window,height=450,width=750)
image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="YourImage.png")
c.create_image(0,0,image=image,anchor=NW)
c.create_text(200,200,text="Hello World",fill="yellow",font="Times 32 bold")
c.pack()


window.mainloop()
```